# How can I get into "androidx" context from within a regular Activity

Tags: android, fragment, androidx

My problem is as follows: I've got a Unity3D app exported to Android Studio. I have added a java plugin for the purpose of using the OnBackPressedDispatcher class included in androidx.activity since the common onBackPressed API will be deprecated soon. The code example from Google is as follows:

```
public class FormEntryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
            true // default to enabled
        ) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                showAreYouSureDialog();
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(
            this, // LifecycleOwner
            callback);
    }
}
```

However, the method "getOnBackPressedDispatcher" is only available in an object of type ComponentActivity or FragmentActivity, the method "requireActivity" only in class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.
The solution that was suggested in another post, to use AppCompatActivity as base class to have access to the SupportFragmentManager, doesn't work here as I can't change the base class for the UnityPlayer Activity.
So the question is: Is there a way to transform/cast a regular Activity object to one of the Activity types in the androidx space or, if that doesn't work, get hold of the available Fragments in androidx space via SupportFragmentManager somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think there's a way. What you can do, however, is copy the functionality from the androidx Activities (`ComponentActivity` and `FragmentActivity`) into your Activity.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't following the [If your app cannot use AndroidX libraries documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture#migrate-app)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake The reason is that the documentation says that using the AndroidX libs is the highly recommended way. So I didn't want to give up on that approach already